# Edit TextView outside of OnCreate or Buttons Java Based

Tags: java, android, textview, oncreate

I am a beginner and have floundered on what should be an easy task. Through OnCreate or through buttons, I can edit any of the textviews through t.append(bla bla bla) but when I try to externalize the editing to another class, it all goes south and the program doesn't launch. This is on Android.

**Main Java File**

```
Public class MainActivity extends Activity

{
public int x = 1;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   setContentView(R.layout.main);

TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.android_happy);

**THIS EDITS THE TEXTVIEW CORRECTLY---->** t.append(x);

MyTask update1 = new MyTask();

**THIS MAKES THE CODE FAIL--->**update1.run();
}
```

**OTHER CLASS FILE**

```
(usual imported packages)

Public class MyTask extends Activity {
@Override
public void run() {

setContentView(R.layout.main);

TextView u = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.android_happy);

u.setText(6+"");
}}
```

Thank you for any advice or places to read that I can go.

Comment: Do you have the method onCreate on the second activity (MyTask)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to declare your `TextView` as instance variable and instantiate it in your `onCreate` method. In that way, you can access your `TextView` in other class.